# How to start rendering before json response is completed react native

Tags: react-native

I am developing news app using react native, and the problem is the startup time is taking too much time (around 3 seconds to load initially and 5 seconds for the  home screen to show up).
I have 36 articles and the json response is big(3000 lines). After analyzing i found that the reason is the waiting time of resolving the function promise that get the articles(after .then).

The function that gets articles:

```
export async function getArticles(){

    try {
        let articles = await fetch(``);
        let result = await articles.json();
        return result;

    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

The home.js that display the articles is :

```
export class HomeScreen extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            data: null,
            isError: false,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        getArticles().then(data => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                data: data
            })
        }, error => {
            Alert.alert("Error", "Something happend, please try again")
        })
    }
```

I tried to simplify the response body by extracting specific fields but there was no difference, and I dont know how to fetch only simple number of articles from the url itself like per_page or something else ... .
Can you advice how to start rendering before waiting the json response to complete?.

Comment: You can use infinite scrolling like you see in the youtube or facebook they load certain number of documents and then as you scroll it loads more data 
here is an link to that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZKUirTtxcg&t=1336s   its in react so it will be helpful

Comment: Yes i check it, but they provide oage number in url , to fetch 10 by 10 for exapmle, but i dont have that in my case.

Comment: if you are using sql then you can use cursor https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-cursor-in-sql/ or you can bring 10 records at a time

Comment: No i am not using sql